# php image upload mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload

I have problem with my script. It uploads image in my hosting server. There created folders with images are missing  from hosting server next day or next week not all images of course - 18-19% of all for 2 weeks. I asked them. They told me- the problem is in my php code. If someone can help I will be happy. May be I add some 0777 in mkdir()???? I don't know. I am thinking at the all time...

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['myfile'])) {
    $ip = getRealIpAddr();
    $usernameupload = $user_data['username'];

    $title = sanitize($_POST['title']);
    $description = sanitize($_POST['description']);
    if (empty($_POST['folder']) === true) { $folder = sanitize($_POST['folder_option']);} else { $folder = sanitize($_POST['folder']);}
    $date = date('M-d-Y');
    $code = "";

    $errors = array();
    $allowed_ext =array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    $file_name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $extension=explode('.',$file_name); 
    $file_ext=strtolower(end($extension));

    if (isset($_POST['submitupload'])) {
        if ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] == ""){
        $errors[] = ' *Upload file';
        } else if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
        $errors[] = ' *Extension not allowed';
        }
    }

    if ($file_size > 5042880) {
        $errors[] = 'File size must be under 5mb';
        }
    if (strlen($folder) > 50) {
        $errors[] = 'Your new folder name must be max 50 characters';
        }

    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please Fill Title';
        }

    if (strlen($_POST['title']) > 255) {
        $errors[] = 'Your title must be max 255 characters';
        }

    if (empty($errors)) {

        require('db.inc.php');

        $charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        $length = 50;

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
            $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);
            $code .= $tmp;
            }

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM files WHERE code='$code'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        while ($numrows != 0) {
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
                $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
                $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);
                $code .= $tmp;
                }
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM files WHERE code='$code'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        }

        mkdir("files/$code");
        mkdir("files/thumbs/$code");


        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "files/$code/".$file_name)) {

        $file = "";     
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES ('', '$usernameupload', '$ip', '$title', '$code', '$folder', '$description', '$file_name', '$file_ext', '$file_size', '$date')");

        $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO votes VALUES ('', '', '', '$code')");

        create_thumb('files/'.$code.'/', $file_name, 'files/thumbs/' . $code . '/');


        header("Location: userdownload.php?code=$code");
        exit();

            }
        }
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="editfill">Image:*</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileup"></td>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php 

            if (isset($_POST['submitupload'])) {
        if ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] == ""){
        echo '<div id="errormsg"> *Upload file </div>';
        } else if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
        echo '<div id="errormsg"> *Allowed extension: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif</div>';
        } else if ($file_size > 5042880) {
        echo '<div id="errormsg"> *File size must be under 5mb </div>';
        }
    }
    ?></td>
    </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="editfill">Title:*</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['submitupload'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['title']); ?>" maxlength="255"></td>
        <tr>
        <td></td>   
            <td><?php 
            if (isset($_POST['submitupload'])) {
            if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
        echo '<div id="errormsg"> *Please fill title </div>';
        }
            if (strlen($_POST['title']) > 255) {
        echo '<div id="errormsg"> *Your title must be max 255 characters</div>';
        }
        }
            ?></td>
         </tr>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="editfill">Create Album:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="folder" id="title" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['submitupload'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['folder']); ?>" maxlength="50">
            </td>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php   
        if (strlen($folder) > 50) {
        echo '<div id="errormsg"> *Your new album name must be max 50 characters</div>';
        }
 ?></td>
        </tr>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="editfill">Your Albums:</td>
            <td>
            <select name="folder_option" class="select">
            <option></option>
        <?php  
        $mysql_folder = mysql_query("SELECT `folder_name` FROM `files` WHERE `username` = '$usernameupload' AND `folder_name` > '' GROUP BY `folder_name` ORDER BY `folder_name` ASC"); 

        while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_folder)) {
                $filefolder = $query_row['folder_name'];

                echo '<option value="' . $filefolder . '">' . $filefolder . '</option>';
                }

        ?>
    </select>
            </td>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="editfill">Description:</td>
            <td><textarea name="description" id="description"><?php if (isset($_POST['submitupload'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['description']); ?></textarea></td>
        <tr><td></td>
            <td>
        </td>
        </tr>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><center><br><input type="submit" name="submitupload" id="submitupload" value="Upload"></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: are you saying some of the photos you upload from the previous 2 weeks are missing?

Comment: Еxactly. They are missing with created folder and image inside.

Comment: you doesn`t define any file deletion in this case and thats very impossible for this code to delete files that created .. Except when you are trying to create folder then insert the images .. maybe it comes up with an error while creating the folder thats why it stops and the folder and images wouldn`t be created but still inserted at database..

Comment: I know. I don't explain to myself how is possible but ... All is possible. There some of the images just are missing next day or next week from my hosting server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to efficiently see if mkdir creation doesnt failed.
   else folder and image surely will not be exist even it is added unto your database.

```
//previous code...
mkdir("files/$code");
mkdir("files/thumbs/$code");

//change to this...
if (!mkdir("files/$code", 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

if (!mkdir("files/thumbs/$code", 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create sub folders...');
}
```

Comment: Uploaded image and no problems with uploading

Comment: I must wait now for result.

Comment: i think so.. rofl.. Cause I don`t see anything else wrong at your code.., but better test it for proven and clear results :)..

Comment: Thank you for support my friend. I'll buy you bottle beer thanks again

Comment: can it just be milk , I don`t drink beers.. or maybe you can just give me another question to solve .. ROFL..

Comment: I don't have for now. Ok milk no problem for you